# HERE Api: How do I request PDE data for Safety_Alerts layer without getting Bad Request?

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am creating an Android App that accesses the HERE Platform Data Extension Api (= PDE). Therefore I first load a map centering on my current location. This works fine so far. Then I try to load data from the PDE for the layer "SAFETY_ALERTS", but I get a 400 Error there with the message "tilexy lists 992 tiles but the limit is 64 tiles".

I am not sure where this "tilexy" comes from. I already researched through as much documentation of the PDE as I could find online, but I couldn't find an answer.

```java
Set<String> layers = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("SAFETY_ALERTS"));
        GeoBoundingBox bbox = map.getBoundingBox();
        final PlatformDataRequest request = PlatformDataRequest.createBoundingBoxRequest(layers, bbox);
        request.execute(new PlatformDataRequest.Listener<PlatformDataResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(PlatformDataResult platformDataResult, PlatformDataRequest.Error error) {
                if (error == null) {                    
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //show error --> Here is where I get
                }
```

I expected to get a PlatformDataItemCollection, which is a List of PlatformDataItems (they implement Map). Instead I got the 400-Error.

Does somebody know where this error comes from and can help me fix my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, it would be advisable to check the API call as it seems that more than 64 coordinates has been passed in tilexy parameter in the rest call. tilexy is a string, which is passed in comma separated sequence of tilex,tiley pairs for the requested tiles. The tilex and tiley values are described in the "tile" resource.

please refer following documentation for more reference

developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-tiles.html

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Found the mistake, the BoundingBox was too big... thanks you :)